# ParseQuery.setSkip() does not work, it takes foreward but even backward

Tags: android, parse-platform

The title explains perfectly what is my problem.
Here's some code, I highlighted just what I thought was important:

```
class Callback extends FindCallback {
    int skip, actualSkip;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query;
    //Constructor wants them as parameters

    done(List obj, Exception e) {
        elaborateResults();
        actualSkip+=skip;
        query.setSkip(actualSkip);
        if (otherResultsToFetch()) {
            query.findInBackground(new Callback(query, skip, actualSkip);
        }
    }

}
```

In another method I call for the first time:

```
  Edit 2: ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("tableName").setLimit(1);

  query.findInBackground(new Callback(query,1,0);
```

And the rows I want to fetch are 4

the elements I fetch are, in order, {A,A,B,A} (where every letter corresponds to a different row in the db)
the rows are not duplicated in the db.

So, what the H**l is going on? =( I need help

Edit: I printed the query.getSkip() and is correctly 0, 1, 2, 3..

Edit 3: I tried to give a different order to the query (query.orderByAscending("key")) but the problems remain, the rows fetched are Z, Z, Y, Z

Comment: `The title explains perfectly what is my problem.` No it doesn't. "Does not work" is not an explanation of anything.

Comment: Yes, but I can't write everything in the title